# Intent.getIntent method not taking empty argument, Android studio showing error

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to use the method Intent.getIntent() in the onCreate method of my activity but Android Studio is showing an error.

The Error:`'getIntent(java.lang.string)' in 'android.content.intent' cannot be applied to '()'`

The Code:

```
public class RedirectActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent intent;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_redirect);
        intent = Intent.getIntent();   
        //...
    }
}
```

I am also being alerted that the method has been deprecated, but that should not throw an error as far as I know. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any static method `getIntent()` without parameters in the `Intent` class.

The static method available in the `Intent` class is the one which takes `Uri` as an argument which creates a new `Intent` by parsing the supplied `Uri`

You should probably get the intent from the activity.

Instead of:

```
intent = Intent.getIntent();
```

Simply use:

```
intent = getIntent();
```